# undefined local variable or method `current_user' when devise routes are defined within a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I build a multitenant app and I have specific logic for authentication in two tenants so I defined the devises routes in my constrained scope (in order to have two sets of namespaced routes, with their own controllers):

```rb
scope(as: 'geea', module: 'geea', constraints: TenantConstraint.new('geea')) do
  devise_for(:users, {
    encryptor: :md5,
    controllers: {
      confirmations:      'geea/users/confirmations',
      sessions:           'geea/users/sessions',
      registrations:      'geea/users/registrations',
      omniauth_callbacks: 'geea/users/omniauth_callbacks',
      passwords:          'geea/users/passwords'
    }
  })

  devise_scope :user do
    namespace :backoffice do
      get    'signin',  to: 'sessions#new',     as: 'new_user_session'
      post   'signin',  to: 'sessions#create',  as: 'user_session'
      delete 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'destroy_user_session'
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that causes Devise helpers not to be available in my controllers.

```
undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Geea::Frontoffice::HomeController:0x007fd14d4a36e0>
```

How could I deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: check whether user is logged in correctly or not,sometimes if user was not logged in successfully then current_user method remains undefined.

Comment: `current_user` should always be defined, but returning nil or the User object. I had no problem before defining routes inside the scope.

Comment: Have you tried to move the ``devise_for`` block outside the scope, and keep the scope inside?

Comment: could you solve this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. I was namespacing an api with a version. Devise fell under the namespaces. Try something like current_api_v1_user